# Output of the comand Put

Tags: output-formatting

I have a do loop in which I "Put" a ListPlot of a list in every iteration by doing

```
Put[ListPlot[list],"file"]
```

While the process is running and is still not finished, I get the desired plots in "file", but once the process is finished, I do not get the plot but the numerical values of the list with something like

```
{"      0.0134559544171447}", " {298.", " 0.013484438740159787}", 
  " {299.", " "}, {"      0.013512496857553435}", " {300.", 
" 0.013540123145712023}}]}", " {}}}", 
" "}, {"  {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1)", " Axes -> True", 
" AxesOrigin -> {0", " 0.0098}", " "}, {"   PlotRange -> {{0.", 
" 300.}", " {0.00977737893161915", " 0.016994445972500355}}", 
" "}, {"   PlotRangeClipping -> True", 
" PlotRangePadding -> "}, {"    {Scaled[0.02]", 
" Scaled[0.02]}}]}"}}
```

this is just a small piece of the output. I am working in the background by using "nohup" and running an .m file (in case it might have something to do with my issue).

What do I have to do so that I always get the ListPlots as output?

Thanks

Comment: why not just output the data(in your case is list)?when you need plot ,import data and then listplot.

Comment: yea, thats an option...

Comment: You might be happier with `Export` rather than `Put`

Comment: I dont know what you are doing, but for me  `Put[Listplot[],file]` puts in the file the same as you get with `ListPlot[..]//InputForm` , and `Get[file]` displays the plot. Show your actual code if you still need help, though just saving the data is probably a better idea anyway